# Sequelize ^6.6.5, bcryot ^5.0.1. Can't hash the user password

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, sequelize.js, bcrypt

could someone help me to use bcrypt in this code I have here?
It's a node.js backend that I'm using in a react-native project, so I would be very grateful if someone could help me out a bit here.

```
1 const User = require('../models/User');
2 const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
3
4 module.exports = {
5
6 async store(req, res) {
7 const { name, age, city, email, password } = req.body;
8
9 const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
10 const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);
11
12 const user = await User.create({ name, age, city, email, password: hash });
13
14 return res.json(user);
15},
16
17 async index(req, res) {
18 const users = await User.findAll();
19
20 return res.json(users);
21 },
22
23 async findById(req, res) {
24 const { id } = req.params;
25 const user = await User.findAll({
26 where: {
27 id: id
28}
29 } );
30
31 return res.json(user);
32},
33
34 };
35
```

I can register if I don't use bcrypt, but now that I'm trying to register by encrypting the password, I get this error:

```
(node:7096) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: data must be a string or Buffer and salt must either be a salt string or a number of rounds at Object.hashSync (F:\nodejs\Rocketseat\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:95 :15)
    at store (F:\nodejs\Rocketseat\src\controllers\UserController.js:10:25)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (F:\nodejs\Rocketseat\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (F:\nodejs\Rocketseat\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (F:\nodejs\Rocketseat\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (F:\nodejs\Rocketseat\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at F:\nodejs\Rocketseat\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (F:\nodejs\Rocketseat\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (F:\nodejs\Rocketseat\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (F:\nodejs\Rocketseat\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
(node:7096) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled rejection promise. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict`
(see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html...). (rejection id: 1)
(node:7096) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promises are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I also use a models folder where my users variables are, that's only this:

```
1 const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
2
3  class User extends Model {
4    static init(sequelize) {
5      super.init({
6        name: DataTypes.STRING,
7        age: DataTypes.INTEGER,
8        city: DataTypes.STRING,
9        email: DataTypes.STRING,
10       password: DataTypes.STRING,
11      }, {
12        sequelize
13      })
14    }
15
16    static associate(models) {
17      this.hasMany(models.Post, { foreignKey: 'user_id', as: 'posts' });
18    }
19  }
20
21 module.exports = User;
22
```

So I thought I have had made enough to use bcrypt on the password, but... Help?

Comment: it seems `password` is not a string? can you console.log it? and also `console.log(typeof password)`?

Comment: Thank you, you are 100% right, I was sending an int value instead of a string as It should be. But just after changing the value to a string  received another error message: Executing (default): INSERT INTO `users` (`id`,`name`,`age`,`city`,`email`,`password`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
(node:16596) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Validation error

Comment: I had to change my code for this:
  async store(req, res) {
    const { name, age, city, email, password } = req.body;
    
    const hash = await cryptography.generateHash(password);
    const user = await User.create({ name, age, city, email, password: hash });

    return res.json(user);
  },
So it worked. Thank for your help

Comment: glad to help :)